# which template should I use for single category post?

Tags: theme-development, templates, template-hierarchy

I have a category `'c program'`. I can show this category using `category.php` template file. I have a post like '`First C program'` under `'c program'` category. So I want to use another template file for this post. As far I know this can be done using `single.php`. But this template file is not showing this post.

more specifically:

- `example.com/category/c-program` (`category.php` is working here).
- `example.com/category/c-program/first-program` (`single.php` is not working here).

Any idea?

Comment: So you have a standard normal post named "First C Program"? Keep in mind that `single.php` applies to all singular posts, not just that one, and is a fallback. Have you tested which template is actually being loaded? Query Monitor exposes that information. Have you checked the template hierarchy diagram? It's definately not a custom post type? Have you created a more specific template already?

Comment: I just post a standard normal post. I explored template hierarchy diagram. It's definately not a custom post type. I created singel.php template.

Comment: Have you considered flipping the problem on its head? What you ask for taken literally would lead to ambiguity problems. E.g. if the post is in more than 1 category, there's no correct answer as to which category template to load, so this becomes a problem. Instead, if you want the post titled `first-program` to have its own template, create `single-first-template.php` instead